# Screen Orientation Resets When Navigating Between Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, rotation

I have an app which navigates between 2 activities. Both activities initialize the requested orientation to the sensor:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

and I don't have any overrides in the layout files:

```
<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainListActivity"
android:background="@drawable/mainbg"
android:scaleType="centerCrop">
```

and my manifest is the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.domain.project">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <activity android:name=".OneOfMyActivities"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_main_list"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_detail"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.NoActionBar">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="my.domain.project.MainListActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The app functions correctly as far as updating orientation when you rotate the device. If you take the device and rotate it into landscape mode, the screen correctly swaps to landscape, and stays there. However, when you navigate to the other activity in the app, the other activity displays in portrait mode, and then immediately shows the rotate animation before going to landscape. So, it obviously knows which orientation it should be in. Why does it go from landscape to portrait and back to landscape? Is there any way to have it remember that it's already in landscape, and initialize the new activity in landscape?

Having the screen jump and rotate every time you navigate, when the user is not moving their device is rather annoying.

I've tried googling for this, but all I seem to find are answers about how to lock screen orientation, or questions asking why the activity restarts when the screen orientation changes. Neither of which are my question. I want to still allow the app to change screen orientation when the user rotates the device, I just want it to remember that state when navigating between activities.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting this

```
android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
```

In your activity tag and remove the then redundant

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR)
```

Comment: DUDE! That fixed it! I've had this problem for 2 months. I thought I was never going to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: Also, just to clarify for anyone else who has this problem. He meant put that in your AndroidManifest.xml on the activity tag.

Comment: Haha that's great. I'm glad I was able to help.